# Парсинг XSD С++

Tags: c++, qt, xml, xsd

Привет всем. Возникла задача, на основе **XML** и **XSD** динамически подгружать интерфейс. Написал **xml** и **xsd** файл к этой xml. Загружаю **xsd** файл в память, проверяю по **xsd** схеме **xml** файл,с помощью библиотеки **libxml2**, выводит все хорошо или есть где нибудь ошибка, но к примеру допустим все хорошо. Следующим этапом провожу парсинг xml файла средствами Qt (QXmlReader), создаю необходимые формы. Теперь необходимо, как то достать из xsd схемы значения ограничения диапазона, типы и другие атрибуты. К примеру в xsd схеме хранится диапазон для формы, пример маленького кусочка большого файла привел ниже:

```
<xs:element name="age">
 <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
     <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
     <xs:maxInclusive value="120"/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Вот мне нужно из определённого элемента в XSD достать: 
1) тип **integer**
2) minInclusive(мин значение диапазона) - **0**
3) maxInclusive(максимальное значение диапазона) - **120**

На основе этих значение для формы к примеру **spinBox** будут заданы ограничения 1) если получили тип **integer** в результате парсинга **xsd**, будет создан объект класса **QIntValidate** (для делегата) и будет установлен **setRange(0,120);** для этого spinBox

**Возможно есть ли какие нибудь библиотеки для парсинга самой XSD, а не только XML? Может кто то покажет пример xsd в libxml2, но я не нашел. Возможно кто то знает хорошие примеры, как это можно сделать или делал это когда-нибудь средствами Qt.**

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Буду рад увидеть вас на Мете в обсуждениях правил сообщества!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Схема XSD - это тоже файл в формате XML. Вы знаете его структуру. Можете тем-же парсером его парсить.

Например, ищете узел с тэгом "xs:element" и со свойством "name" равному "age". В нём - узел с тэгом "xs:simpleType". В нём узел с тегом "xs:restriction". В нем в узлах с тегами "xs:minInclusive" и "xs:maxInclusive" берёте из свойства "value" необходимые вам значения ограничений.

Comment: Спасибо, как будет возможность (завтра-послезавтра) попробую, затем отпишусь сюда.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите "CodeSynthesis XSD", может подойдёт.
Есть более мощный продукт Altova XSD Editor (коммерческий), тоже c++ умеет генерить

Comment: Что то забыл отписаться, у меня все получилось, как MindCleaner сказал. Смотрел CodeSynthesis, но он больше подходит  для генерации с++ классов из xml и xsd.